# PCRE regexp for both subexpressions are present?

Tags: php, regex

I am working with PHP `preg_match` -- how can I find if both `foo` and `bar` are present regardless whether it's `foobar` or `barfoo` or `something bar that foo`. Obviously something like `foo.*bar|bar.*foo` would work but for a sufficiently complex `foo` and `bar` I would vastly prefer not to write them twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's only a test, you can easily make two checks: one for `foo` and the other for `bar`.

Otherwise, if you want that in a single regex, you can make use of positive lookaheads:

```
(?=.*foo)(?=.*bar)
```

Each make sure that `foo` and `bar` respectively are somewhere further in the string with any character (`.*`) from where the regex pointer is.

EDIT: Also, for performance, you can add a beginning of line anchor so that it doesn't have to check every single position in the string if either or both words are not in the string:

```
^(?=.*foo)(?=.*bar)
```

Comment: `(?=.*foo)(?=.*bar)` works but you should really add a `^` start of string anchor to allow it to fail _much_ quicker for strings that don't match. As written it must perform both lookaheads at every position in the string before it can declare match failure.

Answer (score 0):

I think the second assertion is just an overhead, `/^(?=.*?foo).*?bar/` is also enough. And I suggest to use the non-greedy form, if you expect that your strings are found in the text. I should also note, that dot only matches non-newline characters, which might be a problem for multiline strings.